# JavaScript function data handling

Tags: javascript, function

I'm newbie to javascript and I need to now one small thing.
I have this code

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8')
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        if(chunk.length < 50) {
            console.log('end!');
        } else {
            console.log(chunk);
        }
    });
})
```

And I need to operate with variable "chunk" in the rest of code. How I can throw it from the function? - stadart return will not work here of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can just set it as a variable in the containing scope.

```
var ch;
http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8')

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    if(chunk.length < 50) {
        ch = chunk;
    } else {
        console.log(chunk);
    }
});
```

However, since the `chunk` is dealt with asynchronously, due to the AJAX request, you would probably be better off continuing your program by calling a method from inside your callback.

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8')

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    if(chunk.length < 50) {
        doSomethingWithChunk(chunk);
    } else {
        console.log(chunk);
    }
});

function doSomethingWithChunk(chunk) {
    // rest of code here
}
```

EDIT:

To set global variable in nodejs (this is **not** recommended), then you can use the `global` object:

```
GLOBAL.chunk = chunk;
```

Again, this should not be necessary, consider altering your code so that you don't have to use globals.

Comment: But variable ch is still not available out of function content! I wanna use it in whole code over that!

Comment: You didn't specify nodejs in your question.